# Is it possible to mix in a trait using apply?

Tags: scala

I have a trait, call it foo. I have a class, call it MyClass:

```
class MyClass(something: String) { ... }
```

I can do this:

```
val myStuff = new MyClass("hello") with foo
```

What I'd like to do, however, is have my class with a companion object and use apply to create an instance:

```
class MyClass(something: String) { ... }
object MyClass {
  def apply(something: String) = {      
    new MyClass(something)
  }
}
```

The problem is that the following code isn't valid:

```
val myStuff = MyClass("hello") with foo
```

This would use the apply to make an instance of MyClass, but the trait can't be used. Is there a way to do this?

My goal is in test - the trait (foo) contains overrides for a few things in MyClass that lets me use the trait as a data mock. It's precisely what I need, but I'd like to be able to do that without doing a "new." And since I want to mix this into my test code but not in production, putting the "with foo" inside of apply in the companion object isn't an option.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it can't be done with a companion object.
`apply` is like a place holder.
When you do `MyClass("hello") with Foo`  is equivalent to apply("hello") with Foo
apply gets executed first in case of companion object. With class construct its different